# Stuck with Euclidean space geometry exercise

Tags: euclidean-geometry

$ABCD$ is a tetrahedron. $E$ is a point on segment $AD$. $Δ$ is a line of plane $(BCD)$ parallel to $(BC)$.

Line $Δ$ intersects $(BD)$ at $I$ and $(CD)$ at $J$.

Plane $(ABC)$ intersects line $(EI)$ at $M$ and line $(EJ)$ at $N$.

[image: Drawing]

Show that lines $(MN)$ and $(BC)$ are parallel.

---

I am 15 years old (*classe de seconde* in France ≈ 10th grade) and I am stuck. We get that

- $M$ is on line $(AB)$ and $N$ on line $(AC)$
- $\frac{DB}{DI}=\frac{DC}{DJ}=\frac{BC}{IJ}$ since $(BC)$ and $(IJ)$ are parallel (per Thales)
- we'd get the desired result by showing $\frac{AM}{AB}=\frac{AN}{AC}$ or either term is $\frac{MN}{BC}$ (using reciprocal of Thales)
- we'd get the desired result by showing that lines $(MN)$ and $(IJ)$ are parallel (since two lines parallel to a third one are parallel)
- we'd get the above by showing $\frac{EM}{EI}=\frac{EN}{EJ}$ or either term is $\frac{MN}{IJ}$ (using reciprocal of Thales)

Comment: @Jean Marie: thanks for the fixes and simplification. I'm really the father ! See [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/555/fgrieu) if in doubt.

Comment: I understand. I have been in the same situation some years ago with my son...

Comment: I have no solution, but maybe one could  turn this 3D question into a seemingly equivalent 2D issue by proving the fact that the projected line segment B'C' onto the base plane BCD is parallel to IJ ?

Answer (score 5):

You are right in using the recipeocal of Thales. To continue the proof, you need to invoke another Greek guy’s result.

Consider $\frac{AM}{MB}$ and $\frac{AN}{NC}$.
We’d like to show that the two are equal. Where could we get these values from? Well, N is the **intersection** of a line with another line in a triangle so **Menelaus’ Theorem** is your friend here.

Applying Menelaus in triangle ABD with the line E-M-I we obtain that $\frac{AM}{MB}\frac{EA}{AD}\frac{IB}{BD} = 1$ and we obtain a value for $\frac{AM}{MB}$ and similarly for $\frac{AN}{NC}$ applying Menelaus in triangle ACD with the line E-N-J you get that $\frac{AN}{NC}\frac{EA}{AD}\frac{JC}{CD} = 1$. Since $\frac{JC}{CD} =\frac{IB}{BD}$   you have all the ingredients to show that   $\frac{AM}{MB}$ and $\frac{AN}{NC}$ are equal

Comment: That's helpful. It would be perfectly fine if [Menelaus’ Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27s_theorem) was part of the teaching to a 15yo (classe de seconde in France ≈ 10th grade). It's not, and we'll have to adjust that reasoning to use Thales; it does seems within reach.

Comment: The proof of Menelaus does involve “just” Thales but also some cleverly constructed parallels so I am not quite sure whether such a solution, proving Menelaus, would be “easier” in any way, than just learning Menelaus...